# organization's memory limit exceeded

Tags: swisscomdev

During deployment we get an error about exceeding the orgs memory limit:

`You have exceeded your organization's memory limit: app requested more memory than available`

How can we get more memory assigned?

btw. is there any other way then to use SO to ask questions like this? This is really not a tech question and I have to artificially make a long question to get it postable/accepted by SO.

Comment: _"is there any other way then to use SO to ask questions like this?"_ - you mean having to fluff up a oneliner question with nonsense to get it past the quality checks? No, read [ask] and realise that you should share your research in your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not presented as a question about computing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your organisation reaches the quotas of Swisscom Application Cloud you can get in contact with Swisscom as described here: https://developer.swisscom.com/support